# Cannot pass argument through /proc/<pid>/fd/0

Tags: process, io-redirection, signals, file-descriptors

I have written a basic C++ program as such:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  int foo;
  std::cin >> foo;
  FILE* fd = fopen("./output", "a+");
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << getpid() << std::endl;
  fputs(ss.str().c_str(), fd);
}
```

The code simply expects input from standard input, and appends its process id to an output file. After successful compilation, I execute the binary as background process `./my_binary&`, check its pid with `jobs -l`, and try to pass a dummy integer to it either with `printf "6\0" >/proc/<pid>/fd/0` or `echo -e "6\n" >/proc/<pid>/fd/0`. The process does not write in output file and exit as I expect it to. What am I doing wrong here? I can see the `0` descriptor in the process' proc directory but does it get somehow blocked when the process it thrown in the background?

Note that in contrast, I can exhibit the expected behaviour by `fg <n>`ing and manually entering an integer.

**Edit:** As per Kusalananda's comment, I have realized that a `SIGTTIN` signal is being emitted for processes which have been backgrounded while expecting input from tty.

**Edit:** Failing to find a way to mitigate `SIGTTINT` issue, I decided to use a named pipe instead of `stdin`. The code has been changed so (also I switched to C, having realized I ended up using pure C anyway):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char input[3]; 
  read(7, input, 2);
  int num = atoi(input);
  char output[256];
  memset(output, 0, 256);
  sprintf(output, "%d : %d\n", getpid(), num);
  write(13, output, strlen(output));

  return 0;
}
```

I created a pipe: `mkfifo input_pipe`, and called the process as `./process 7<input_pipe 13>>output`, passing the arguments into `input_pipe`.

Comment: What is the status of the process after you try to write to it? Most programs that read from the terminal as its standard input enters a "stopped" state when put into the background, since it blocks on the read until a terminal is present.  Try e.g. `( read thing ) &` in the shell.

Comment: Great, this has been a good starting point. The process is indeed being stopped, and it is also rejecting `kill -SIGCONT <pid>` continue signals. I have looked further into it and seen that a `SIGTTIN` signal is being emitted for processes which have been backgrounded while expecting input from tty. I'll see if I can trap and ignore this signal, or get input from some other file than stdin. I will keep here posted.

Comment: If your intent is to have the process act like a daemon that can accept input from some unrelated process, the time-tested way of doing this is to have it read from a named pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ended up doing that and edited the question accordingly. I have a few of these bckground jobs and once one pulls the input data out of the pipe, others starve. Do you know of any ways to deal with this more elegant than perhaps giving each process a different pipe, and copying the data to each of them, or appending n numbers of repeated input?